# no class def found WSDL2JAVA axis 1.4

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

heyy I am trying to get client java classes using axis 1.4 but I see NO CLASS DEF FOUND when I try to run the below command from the command prompt ... Please help why

```
WSDL file location: C:\
WSDL2JAVA .class location: C:\axis-1_4\lib\org\apache\axis\wsdl\WSDL2JAVA


C:\>java -classpath \axis-1_4\lib org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -v -o -s d:\gen
erate C:\MyWebService.wsdl


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lo
gging.LogFactory
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:4
5)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45
)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory
.java:41)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java
:33)
        at org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle.<clinit>(ProjectResourceBu
ndle.java:53)
        at org.apache.axis.i18n.MessagesConstants.<clinit>(MessagesConstants.jav
a:32)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:36)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java.<clinit>(WSDL2Java.java:112)
```

Comment: obviously, you don't have in classpath class `org.apache.commons.lo
gging.LogFactory`. If you have directory with jar files, you should explicitly add all jars in classpath, like  -classpath axis-1_4\lib\axis.jar;axis-1_4\lib\saaj.jar;axis-1_4\lib\common-logging.jar ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether commons-logging.jar is on your classpath (in your example, at C:\axis-1_4\lib).  Look at this [guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Installing_Axis_and_Using_this_Guide), section "Installing Axis and Using this Guide".

UPD: It just occured to me, that you need to use wildcard to add all jars in your "lib" folder to classpath: C:\axis-1_4\lib*

Take a look at [this Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)